# How to change the text in the thread group display in CDT-based eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I have a CDT-based debugger and want to add some information into the lettering in the thread node. I want the lettering surrounded by the red rectangle to display some additional information (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot]

AFAIR, the format string for this label is set in the property `ThreadVMNode_No_columns__text_format` in file `C:\Users\...\workspace\org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui\src\org\eclipse\cdt\dsf\gdb\internal\ui\viewmodel\launch\MessagesForGdbLaunchVM.properties`.

```
# {0} - name available, 0=not available/1=available
# {1} - name
# {2} - ID available, 0=not available/1=available
# {3} - ID
# {4} - OS Thread ID available, 0=not available/1=available
# {5} - OS Thread ID
# {6} - Core available, 0=not available/1=available
# {7} - Core 
# {8} - 0=running/1=suspended
# {9} - state change reason available, 0=not available/1=available
# {10} - state change reason
# {11} - state change details available, 0=not available/1=available
# {12} - state change details
ThreadVMNode_No_columns__text_format={0,choice,0#Thread|1#{1}}{2,choice,0#|1# [{3}]}{4,choice,0#|1# {5}}{6,choice,0#|1# [core: {7}]} ({8,choice,0#Running|1#Suspended}{9,choice,0#|1# : {10}}{11,choice,0#|1# : {12}})
```

This format string is used in method `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.internal.ui.viewmodel.launch.ThreadVMNode.createLabelProvider()`:

```
public class ThreadVMNode extends AbstractThreadVMNode 
    implements IElementLabelProvider, IElementMementoProvider
{
    [...]

    @Override
    protected IElementLabelProvider createLabelProvider() {
        PropertiesBasedLabelProvider provider = new PropertiesBasedLabelProvider();

        provider.setColumnInfo(
            PropertiesBasedLabelProvider.ID_COLUMN_NO_COLUMNS, 
            new LabelColumnInfo(new LabelAttribute[] { 
                // Text is made of the thread name followed by its state and state change reason. 
                new GdbExecutionContextLabelText(
                    MessagesForGdbLaunchVM.ThreadVMNode_No_columns__text_format,
                    new String[] { 
                        ExecutionContextLabelText.PROP_NAME_KNOWN, 
                        PROP_NAME, 
                        ExecutionContextLabelText.PROP_ID_KNOWN, 
                        ILaunchVMConstants.PROP_ID, 
                        IGdbLaunchVMConstants.PROP_OS_ID_KNOWN, 
                        IGdbLaunchVMConstants.PROP_OS_ID, 
                        IGdbLaunchVMConstants.PROP_CORES_ID_KNOWN, 
                        IGdbLaunchVMConstants.PROP_CORES_ID,
                        ILaunchVMConstants.PROP_IS_SUSPENDED,
                        ExecutionContextLabelText.PROP_STATE_CHANGE_REASON_KNOWN, 
                        ILaunchVMConstants.PROP_STATE_CHANGE_REASON,
                        ExecutionContextLabelText.PROP_STATE_CHANGE_DETAILS_KNOWN,
                        ILaunchVMConstants.PROP_STATE_CHANGE_DETAILS}),
```

AFAIK in order to add a new piece of information to the display it is necessary to

1. override the format string `MessagesForGdbLaunchVM.properties` and
2. add the new string into the string array in the call to the constructor `GdbExecutionContextLabelText`.

What is the best way to do both these things (preferably not changing the code of the Eclipse/CDT core classes) ?

**Update 1 (12.09.2014 19:56 MSK):** Tried to use a custom debug presentation model by adding an extension, but the class `MyCompanyDebugModelPresentation` is not called anyhwere.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugModelPresentations">
      <debugModelPresentation
            class="com.mycompany.internal.debug.ui.model.MyCompanyDebugModelPresentation"
            id="com.mycompany.internal.debug.ui.model.MyCompanyDebugModelPresentation">
      </debugModelPresentation>
   </extension>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I ran into same problem where my custom debug presentation model is not called. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the text shown above, you need to modify a number of files and settings, which are shown in the matrix below.

[image: Morphology matrix]

You can read this image as follows:

1. In your project, specify the extension point `org.eclipse.core.run.adapters` (start of the red line) so that it points to
2. your subclass of `GdbAdapterFactory`.
3. Modify that class so that it returns your subclass of `GdbViewModelAdapter` etc.

You go through that chain until you arrive at the `ThreadVMNode` class (or your subclass), which determines what values are shown in the tree.

Comment: Do you need to also subclass *GdbLaunchDelegate*? Because defining own *GdbAdapterFactory* isn't enough (it won't get called).

Comment: @Witriol Maybe. I don't remember any more and the code doesn't belong to me.